# Oscillation when using orientation field of move_base with teb_local_planner

Tags: gazebo, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am having an issue with the orientation fields of the move_base package and the teb_local_planner.

At first I would just set the orientation.w field to 1.0 and leave the xyz components set to 0. However, now I want to make the robot have a specific orientation when it reaches its goal location.

My train of thought was that if I wanted to rotate the robot around its base that I would have to rotate 0.5 * PI around its yaw axis. If I change the yaw component in my gazebo simulation then I can indeed rotate the robot around its y-axis.

I found [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions) on the ROS wiki which states that you can convert a roll, pitch, yaw rotation to a quaternion.

Suppose my RPY respectively are [0, 0, 0.5 * PI] then the Quaternion is (w,x,y,z) (0.707107, 0, 0, 0.707107) move_base s canaccepts this as a valid quaternion and thus the goal is active. However, the robot starts to oscillate due to its local planner. I added an image of the RVIZ view where I visualized both the local and global plan. The robot stays on the first pose in the red poseArray and moves back and forward.

[image: RVIZ view of the global and local plan.]

Is my quaternion input incorrect or am I using the orientation field incorrectly?
My goal is to have the robot arrive at its goal location with a specific orientation.

Here is the output of my navigation nodes:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /move_base/base_local_planner: teb_local_planner...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[0.25, 0.154], [...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius: 0.55
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint: [[0.25, 0.154], [...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height: 10.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius: 0.55
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 40.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution: 1
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency: 60.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width: 10.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/debug: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq: 50.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame: map
 * /robot_pose_ekf/self_diagnose: False
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout: 1.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used: False
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    link1_broadcaster (tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher)
    link2_broadcaster (tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[link1_broadcaster-1]: started with pid [19739]
process[link2_broadcaster-2]: started with pid [19740]
process[robot_pose_ekf-3]: started with pid [19758]
process[map_server-4]: started with pid [19776]
process[move_base-5]: started with pid [19841]
[ INFO] [1540834009.296069299, 13.907000000]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1540834009.310812145, 13.922000000]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1540834009.317225170, 13.928000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1540834009.520453286, 14.132000000]: Resizing costmap to 100 X 100 at 1.000000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1540834009.621709934, 14.232000000]: Received a 100 X 100 map at 1.000000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1540834009.626584742, 14.237000000]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1540834009.628411482, 14.239000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1540834009.638543716, 14.249000000]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1540834009.685154386, 14.296000000]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1540834009.699557342, 14.311000000]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1540834009.703080097, 14.314000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1540834009.705428648, 14.317000000]: Resizing costmap to 100 X 100 at 1.000000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1540834009.806388473, 14.417000000]: Received a 100 X 100 map at 1.000000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1540834009.811111339, 14.422000000]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1540834009.814059193, 14.425000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1540834009.824545616, 14.435000000]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1540834009.866551233, 14.477000000]: Created local_planner teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1540834009.920261537, 14.531000000]: No robot footprint model specified for trajectory optimization. Using point-shaped model.
[ INFO] [1540834009.920337374, 14.531000000]: Parallel planning in distinctive topologies enabled.
[ INFO] [1540834009.920377444, 14.531000000]: No costmap conversion plugin specified. All occupied costmap cells are treaten as point obstacles.
[ INFO] [1540834010.103009231, 14.714000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [1540834010.108103576, 14.719000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [1540834010.143028158, 14.754000000]: odom received!
```

Sometimes (not always) these warnings are shown:

```
[ WARN] [1540833817.329080357, 41.430000000]: TebLocalPlannerROS: possible oscillation (of the robot or its local plan) detected. Activating recovery strategy (prefer current turning direction during optimization).
[ INFO] [1540833840.461887304, 64.530000000]: TebLocalPlannerROS: oscillation recovery disabled/expired.
[ WARN] [1540833864.453728681, 88.480000000]: TebLocalPlannerROS: possible oscillation (of the robot or its local plan) detected. Activating recovery strategy (prefer current turning direction during optimization).
```

Excuse me if the answer is very obvious. I looked through all the related questions and tutorials on the ROS wiki and this website but I could not find a solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance! I hope I did all the formatting correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307068/oscillation-when-using-orientation-field-of-move_base-with-teb_local_planner./) by [mliefaard](https://answers.ros.org/users/38254/mliefaard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-30**:
How are you giving the goals? The moving of the red poseArray is probably due to the planner re-planning the path. Teb local planner requires a lot of tuning and is not as intuitive as the other planners. You can try changing the goal tolerance parameters (yaw_goal_tolerance, xy_goal_tolerance)

**Comment by [mliefaard](https://answers.ros.org/users/38254/mliefaard/) on 2018-10-30**:
@pavel92 I am giving my goals using the actionlib interface for move_base:

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
```

This is the correct way to give movement goals right?

I am currently looking into changing the parameters, thanks for your response

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-30**:
You can give navigation goals directly in RViz using the [2D Nav Goal](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack#A2D_Nav_Goal) and allows you to easily set the desired orientation

**Comment by [mliefaard](https://answers.ros.org/users/38254/mliefaard/) on 2018-10-30**:
Yes, the navigation goals set directly in the RViz interface do not cause the same issue. I did not know that that was using a 2D Nav Goal so I am going to try to use 2D Nav Goal from my C++ node and see if I encounter the same issue as with the actionlib interface.

**Comment by [mliefaard](https://answers.ros.org/users/38254/mliefaard/) on 2018-10-30**:
The issue still persists if I use 2D Nav Goals published to move_base_simple/goal. Sometimes the teb_local_planner just does not generate a valid PoseArray to follow. It seems like it is trying to strafe as seen in the image that I added. Could this be caused by my parameters for teb_local_planner?

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2018-10-30**:
can you please edit your question and add the teb_local_planner params?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-10-31**:
If the robot rotates to the desired orientation with the goals set in RViz that means that probably the problem is not coming from the goal tolerance parameters from teb_local_planner params but may be coming from different parameters so please post your teb_local_planner_params.yaml file

**Comment by [mliefaard](https://answers.ros.org/users/38254/mliefaard/) on 2018-10-31**:
Sorry for the late response. I spent a lot of time configuring teb_local_planner but the problem persisted so I eventually decided to try other planners as pavel92 suggested earlier. eband_local_planner is working perfectly for me.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a lot of debugging it turned out that my teb_local_planner configuration was the problem since the problem also persisted when I issued a goal in RViz instead of from code.

As @pavel92 noted, teb_local_planner requires a lot of fine tuning. So I eventually gave up and switched to eband_local_planner which works perfectly for my use case. In my experience eband_local_planner was way simpler to configure and it worked immediately for my diff_drive robot.

(Unfortunately I cannot mark this as answered because I don't have enough points)

---

Originally posted by [mliefaard](https://answers.ros.org/users/38254/mliefaard/) with karma: 26 on 2018-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1